# How to use Messenger webapp with a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-messenger

I am trying the [Facebook Customer Chat plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/) on my website. This plugin sends messages directly to your Facebook page. Now I want to get notifications on incoming messages right away and be able to reply using the webapp https://www.messenger.com

However, messenger.com only shows messages from my private account and I cannot find a way of how to switch to my Facebook page.

I do not want to use: https://www.facebook.com/MYSITE/inbox

Is there any way of how to add the page to messenger.com?

PS: For my mobile I found this Android App: [Facebook Pages Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.pages.app&hl=en). But I'd like to be able to reply on messenger.com because it is way faster.